# Experimental verification of Phase Reversal of light

Tags: optics, reflection

Light after reflection, undergoes phase reversal of 180 degrees when incident from a rarer to denser medium, is there a way to experimentally prove this?
I have got a He-Ne laser as a source. Can I use a combination of wave plates and a polarizer and analyzer setup for designing an experiment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes use laser-> linear polarizer (optional if laser is already linearly polarized)-> wave plate (with you get elliptical polarization) then either:

- waveplate -> analyser or
- mirror ->waveplate -> analyser

  you should get different results because the rotation direction is different after the mirror.